# I am getting "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException" on upgrading from spring 2.5 to 4 in my beans xml

Tags: spring, jboss, migration, ejb

I'm trying to Upgrade my spring web application from spring 2.5 to spring 4.
I am also Upgrading my application from weblogic to jboss eap 7.2.

My Application uses EJB stateless bean mapping like below 
@Stateless(name = "xxxxxFacade", mappedName = "xxxxxxLogging")

My Bean Xml is like below

Bean XML:

```
<bean id="xxxxxFacade"
        class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"
            value="msgLogging#com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxLoggingFacade" />
        <property name="businessInterface"
            value="com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxLoggingFacade" />
    </bean>
```

On Starting Jboss EAP 7.2 im getting the below Exception

Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxxxFacade' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: msgLogging#com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxLoggingFacade -- service jboss.naming.context.java."msgLogging#com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxLoggingFacade"

Not able find the rootcause whether this is due to jboss or spring upgrade ,please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Jboss upgrade , ejb is getting deployed in a different way , we need to specify the value of jndi like below

ejb:applcation/module/uniqueName!FullPathofJavaClass.

EX:

```
<property name="jndiName"           value="ejb:ApplcationName/ModuleName/UniqueName!com.xx.xx.xx.xxxFacade" />
```

Issue resolved after this.